# Customise a SharePoint List Form into Sections/Tabs/Pages

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint solution which uses a list with around 20 different pieces of data.  I would like to be able to break these up into sections/pages/tabs so that the user experience in populating and editing these is not so poor.

I know how to use SPD (SharePoint Designer) to customize list forms and was wondering if anyone knew of a technique for achieving this.

I have looked at using a MultiView control but this appears to screw up the rendering within the form.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: You could try the [Rico Accordion](http://demos.openrico.org/demos/accordion) to divide the form.

Comment: Take a look at this [SharePoint custom list form with Tab-style UI](http://arunduttgp.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/sharepoint-custom-list-form-with-tab-style-ui/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* create some Javascript to hide fields until necessary, but it is going to be a hard slog to get it right. It could be easier to create a custom .NET form for the data and use the object model to store the list data.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Forms Designer tool: http://spform.com. It allows you to create rich dynamic forms with tabs based on jquery-ui tabs.

Comment: I am looking for a free tabs solution not a priced/licensed one.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably modify the current form and add div tags that show or hide, through javascript, based on a click somewhere. This would avoid additional .NET code altogether, and therefore maybe the multiview issue you saw.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a nice [tab control](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) that you could leverage combined with some validation to make sure the form isn't submitted if the user hasn't filled out all pages. Before you attach the jQuery, you'll want to split the existing form into separate `div`-wrapped tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [PowerForms](http://www.bpc.gr/default.aspx?page=products-and-solutions/sharepoint/bpc-power-forms/en). It supports tabs and free control positioning (uses silverlight).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into [this](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/01/18/tabs-for-sharepoint-forms-aspx/) javascript way to split forms into tabs. Might be of use to you?
Click for [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQmQI.png) (since I'm not allowed to post images yet...)

Comment: the above link  didn't work , its broken or  its content been removed.

Comment: Nice catch @SaMolPPp. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Info path forms support this but you have to deploy them in a Form Library instead of a list.  You can filter a repeating section based on other fields within the form and only display the fields based on your previous selection.  It is the easiest way, not sure if you have InfoPath and the server/licensing set up to use infopath forms?